# Is it possible to create the producer consumer problem with condition variables and signal instead of broadcast?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

I am trying to run the producer-consumer problem while using`pthread_cond_signal()` instead of `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, however, I attempted a lot of things and can't seem to do it (if I choose `n` producers and `one` consumer then the consumer finishes but not all producers finish, some are stuck on full queue so the problem never finishes executing. I got the [initial code](https://github.com/brentmitchell25/EECS-678/blob/master/Lab6/pthreads_pc/producer_consumer.c) from someone else GitHub and I am trying to edit it to accomplish that (you can view the code on the attached link and I will paste it at the end of the post). The relevant parts here are the producer and consumer functions, currently I have the following:

Consumer:

```
void *consumer (void *carg)
{
  queue  *fifo;
  int     item_consumed;
  pcdata *mydata;
  int     my_tid;
  int    *total_consumed;

  mydata = (pcdata *) carg;

  fifo           = mydata->q;
  total_consumed = mydata->count;
  my_tid         = mydata->tid;

  while (1) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(fifo->mutex); //start of the critical section
 
    while (fifo->empty && *total_consumed != WORK_MAX) {
      printf ("con %d:   EMPTY.\n", my_tid);
      pthread_cond_wait(fifo->notEmpty, fifo->mutex); //if queue is empty then wait for signal that it has something to start consuming
    }

 
    if (*total_consumed >= WORK_MAX) {
       pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex); //if max work is reached then unlock the mutex and exit
      break;
    }
    queueRemove (fifo, &item_consumed); //reaching this means that queue isn\t empty so just consume
    (*total_consumed)++;
    do_work(CONSUMER_CPU,CONSUMER_CPU);

    printf ("con %d:   %d.\n", my_tid, item_consumed);

    pthread_cond_signal(fifo->notFull); //consumption is done so queue isn't full, signal to producer
    pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex);
  }

  printf("con %d:   exited\n", my_tid);
  return (NULL);
}
```

Producer:

```
void *producer (void *parg)
{
  queue  *fifo;
  int     item_produced;
  pcdata *mydata;
  int     my_tid;
  int    *total_produced;

  mydata = (pcdata *) parg;

  fifo           = mydata->q;
  total_produced = mydata->count;
  my_tid         = mydata->tid;

  while (1) {
      
    pthread_mutex_lock(fifo->mutex);
    do_work(PRODUCER_CPU, PRODUCER_BLOCK);
 
  
    while (fifo->full && *total_produced != WORK_MAX) {
      printf ("prod %d:  FULL.\n", my_tid);
      pthread_cond_wait(fifo->notFull, fifo->mutex); //if queue is full then wait for signal that is not anyone to start producing
  
    }

    if (*total_produced >= WORK_MAX) {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex); //if total work reached then exit
      break;
    }

    item_produced = (*total_produced)++;
    queueAdd (fifo, item_produced);


    printf("prod %d:  %d.\n", my_tid, item_produced);
    pthread_cond_signal(fifo->notEmpty); //reaching this means we produced something so signal that queue is not empty
    pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex);
  }

  printf("prod %d:  exited\n", my_tid);
  return (NULL);
}
```

My problem is that not all threads are getting the signal to exit, for example running up to 13 producers and one consumer worked but everything above 13 producers with one consumer gets stuck, here is an execution sample of running 14 producers with one consumer:

```
con 0:   EMPTY.
prod 3:  2.
prod 9:  FULL.
prod 11:  FULL.
prod 13:  FULL.
prod 0:  0.
prod 8:  3.
prod 6:  1.
prod 12:  FULL.
prod 7:  4.
prod 10:  FULL.
prod 1:  FULL.
prod 2:  FULL.
prod 5:  FULL.
prod 4:  FULL.
prod 9:  5.
prod 3:  FULL.
prod 0:  FULL.
prod 6:  FULL.
prod 8:  FULL.
prod 7:  FULL.
prod 9:  FULL.
con 0:   0.
prod 11:  6.
prod 13:  FULL.
prod 11:  FULL.
con 0:   1.
prod 12:  7.
prod 10:  FULL.
prod 12:  FULL.
con 0:   2.
prod 1:  8.
prod 2:  FULL.
prod 1:  FULL.
con 0:   3.
prod 4:  9.
prod 5:  FULL.
prod 4:  FULL.
con 0:   4.
prod 3:  10.
prod 0:  FULL.
prod 3:  FULL.
con 0:   5.
prod 6:  11.
prod 8:  FULL.
prod 6:  FULL.
con 0:   6.
prod 7:  12.
prod 9:  FULL.
prod 7:  FULL.
con 0:   7.
prod 13:  13.
prod 11:  FULL.
prod 13:  FULL.
con 0:   8.
prod 12:  14.
prod 10:  FULL.
prod 12:  FULL.
con 0:   9.
prod 2:  15.
prod 1:  FULL.
prod 2:  FULL.
con 0:   10.
prod 5:  16.
prod 4:  FULL.
prod 5:  FULL.
con 0:   11.
prod 3:  17.
prod 0:  FULL.
prod 3:  FULL.
con 0:   12.
prod 8:  18.
prod 6:  FULL.
prod 8:  FULL.
con 0:   13.
prod 9:  19.
prod 7:  FULL.
prod 9:  FULL.
con 0:   14.
prod 11:  20.
prod 13:  FULL.
prod 11:  FULL.
con 0:   15.
prod 10:  21.
prod 12:  FULL.
prod 10:  FULL.
con 0:   16.
prod 2:  22.
prod 1:  FULL.
prod 2:  FULL.
con 0:   17.
prod 4:  23.
prod 5:  FULL.
prod 4:  FULL.
con 0:   18.
prod 0:  24.
prod 3:  FULL.
prod 0:  FULL.
con 0:   19.
prod 6:  25.
prod 8:  FULL.
prod 6:  FULL.
con 0:   20.
prod 7:  26.
prod 9:  FULL.
prod 7:  FULL.
con 0:   21.
prod 11:  27.
prod 13:  FULL.
prod 11:  FULL.
con 0:   22.
prod 12:  28.
prod 10:  FULL.
prod 12:  FULL.
con 0:   23.
prod 1:  29.
prod 2:  exited
prod 1:  exited
con 0:   24.
prod 4:  exited
prod 5:  exited
con 0:   25.
prod 3:  exited
prod 0:  exited
con 0:   26.
prod 8:  exited
prod 6:  exited
con 0:   27.
prod 9:  exited
prod 7:  exited
con 0:   28.
prod 13:  exited
prod 11:  exited
con 0:   29.
con 0:   exited
prod 10:  exited
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Full code if anyone is interested (it is long but I guess most relevant parts are already in the methods I have posted):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/*
 * Define constants for how big the shared queue should be and how
 * much total work the produceers and consumers should perform
 */

#define QUEUESIZE 5
#define WORK_MAX 30

/*
 * These constants specify how much CPU bound work the producer and
 * consumer do when processing an item. They also define how long each
 * blocks when producing an item. Work and blocking are implemented
 * int he do_work() routine that uses the msleep() routine to block
 * for at least the specified number of milliseconds.
 */
#define PRODUCER_CPU   25
#define PRODUCER_BLOCK 10
#define CONSUMER_CPU   25
#define CONSUMER_BLOCK 10

/*****************************************************
 *   Shared Queue Related Structures and Routines    *
 *****************************************************/
typedef struct {
  int buf[QUEUESIZE];   /* Array for Queue contents, managed as circular queue */
  int head;             /* Index of the queue head */
  int tail;             /* Index of the queue tail, the next empty slot */  

  int full;             /* Flag set when queue is full  */
  int empty;            /* Flag set when queue is empty */

  pthread_mutex_t *mutex;     /* Mutex protecting this Queue's data */
  pthread_cond_t  *notFull;   /* Used by producers to await room to produce*/
  pthread_cond_t  *notEmpty;  /* Used by consumers to await something to consume*/
} queue;

/*
 * Create the queue shared among all producers and consumers
 */
queue *queueInit (void)
{
  queue *q;

  /*
   * Allocate the structure that holds all queue information
   */
  q = (queue *)malloc (sizeof (queue));
  if (q == NULL) return (NULL);

  /*
   * Initialize the state variables. See the definition of the Queue
   * structure for the definition of each.
   */
  q->empty = 1;  
  q->full  = 0;   

  q->head  = 0;   
  q->tail  = 0;   

  /*
   * Allocate and initialize the queue mutex
   */
  q->mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_mutex_t));
  pthread_mutex_init (q->mutex, NULL);

  /*
   * Allocate and initialize the notFull and notEmpty condition
   * variables
   */
  q->notFull = (pthread_cond_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_cond_t));
  pthread_cond_init (q->notFull, NULL);

  q->notEmpty = (pthread_cond_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_cond_t));
  pthread_cond_init (q->notEmpty, NULL);

  return (q);
}

/*
 * Delete the shared queue, deallocating dynamically allocated memory
 */
void queueDelete (queue *q)
{
  /*
   * Destroy the mutex and deallocate its memory
   */
  pthread_mutex_destroy (q->mutex);
  free (q->mutex);
  
  /*
   * Destroy and deallocate the condition variables
   */
  pthread_cond_destroy (q->notFull);
  free (q->notFull);

  pthread_cond_destroy (q->notEmpty);
  free (q->notEmpty);

  /*
   * Deallocate the queue structure
   */
  free (q);
}

void queueAdd (queue *q, int in)
{
  
  /*
   * Put the input item into the free slot
   */
  q->buf[q->tail] = in;
  q->tail++;

  /*
   * wrap the value of tail around to zero if we reached the end of
   * the array. This implements the circularity of the queue inthe
   * array.
   */
  if (q->tail == QUEUESIZE)
    q->tail = 0;

  /*
   * If the tail pointer is equal to the head, then the enxt empty
   * slot in the queue is occupied and the queue is FULL
   */
  if (q->tail == q->head)
    q->full = 1;

  /*
   * Since we just added an element to the queue, it is certainly not
   * empty.
   */
  q->empty = 0;

  return;
}

void queueRemove (queue *q, int *out)
{
  /*
   * Copy the element at head into the output variable and increment
   * the head pointer to move to the next element.
   */
  *out = q->buf[q->head];
  q->head++;

  /*
   * Wrap the index around to zero if it reached the size of the
   * array. This implements the circualrity of the queue int he array.
   */
  if (q->head == QUEUESIZE)
    q->head = 0;

  /*
   * If head catches up to tail as we delete an item, then the queue
   * is empty.
   */
  if (q->head == q->tail)
    q->empty = 1;

  /*
   * since we took an item out, the queue is certainly not full
   */
  q->full = 0;

  return;
}

/******************************************************
 *   Producer and Consumer Structures and Routines    *
 ******************************************************/
/*
 * Argument struct used to pass consumers and producers thier
 * arguments.  
 * 
 * q     - arg provides a pointer to the shared queue. 
 *
 * count - arg is a pointer to a counter for this thread to track how
 *         much work it did.
 *
 * tid   - arg provides the ID number of the producer or consumer, 
 *         whichis also its index into the array of thread structures.
 * 
 */
typedef struct {
  queue *q;       
  int   *count;   
  int    tid;
} pcdata;

int memory_access_area[100000];


/*
 * Sleep for a specified number of milliseconds. We use this to
 * simulate I/O, since it will block the process. Different lengths fo
 * sleep simulate interaction with different devices.
 */
void msleep(unsigned int milli_seconds)
{
  struct timespec req = {0}; /* init struct contents to zero */
  time_t          seconds;

  /*
   * Convert number of milliseconds input to seconds and residual
   * milliseconds to handle the cse where input is more than one
   * thousand milliseconds.
   */
  seconds        = (milli_seconds/1000);
  milli_seconds  = milli_seconds - (seconds * 1000);

  /*
   * Fill in the time_spec's seconds and nanoseconds fields. Note we
   * multiply millisconds by 10^6 to convert to nanoseconds.
   */
  req.tv_sec  = seconds;
  req.tv_nsec = milli_seconds * 1000000L;

  /*
   * Sleep for the required period. The first parameter specifies how
   * long. In theory this thread can be awakened before the period is
   * over, perhaps by a signal. If so the timespec specified by the
   * second argument is filled in with how much time int he original
   * request is left. We use the same one. If this happens, we just
   * call nanosleep again to sleep for what remains of the origianl
   * request.
   */
  while(nanosleep(&req, &req)==-1) {
    printf("restless\n");
    continue;
  }

}

/*
 * Simulate doing work. 
 */
void do_work(int cpu_iterations, int blocking_time)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int local_var;

  local_var = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < cpu_iterations; j++ ) {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
      local_var = memory_access_area[i];
    }
  }
  
  if ( blocking_time > 0 ) {
    msleep(blocking_time);
  }
}

void *producer (void *parg)
{
  queue  *fifo;
  int     item_produced;
  pcdata *mydata;
  int     my_tid;
  int    *total_produced;

  mydata = (pcdata *) parg;

  fifo           = mydata->q;
  total_produced = mydata->count;
  my_tid         = mydata->tid;

  /*
   * Continue producing until the total produced reaches the
   * configured maximum
   */
  while (1) {
      
   
    pthread_mutex_lock(fifo->mutex);
    do_work(PRODUCER_CPU, PRODUCER_BLOCK);
 
    /*
     * If the queue is full, we have no place to put anything we
     * produce, so wait until it is not full.
     */
    while (fifo->full && *total_produced != WORK_MAX) {
      printf ("prod %d:  FULL.\n", my_tid);
      pthread_cond_wait(fifo->notFull, fifo->mutex);
  
    }

    /*
     * Check to see if the total produced by all producers has reached
     * the configured maximum, if so, we can quit.
     */
    if (*total_produced >= WORK_MAX) {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex);
      break;
    }

    /*
     * OK, so we produce an item. Increment the counter of total
     * widgets produced, and add the new widget ID, its number, to the
     * queue.
     */
    item_produced = (*total_produced)++;
    queueAdd (fifo, item_produced);

    /*
     * Announce the production outside the critical section 
     */
    printf("prod %d:  %d.\n", my_tid, item_produced);
    pthread_cond_signal(fifo->notEmpty);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex);
  }

  printf("prod %d:  exited\n", my_tid);
  return (NULL);
}

void *consumer (void *carg)
{
  queue  *fifo;
  int     item_consumed;
  pcdata *mydata;
  int     my_tid;
  int    *total_consumed;

  mydata = (pcdata *) carg;

  fifo           = mydata->q;
  total_consumed = mydata->count;
  my_tid         = mydata->tid;

  /*
   * Continue producing until the total consumed by all consumers
   * reaches the configured maximum
   */
  while (1) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(fifo->mutex);
    /*
     * If the queue is empty, there is nothing to do, so wait until it
     * si not empty.
     */
    while (fifo->empty && *total_consumed != WORK_MAX) {
      printf ("con %d:   EMPTY.\n", my_tid);
      pthread_cond_wait(fifo->notEmpty, fifo->mutex);
    }

    /*
     * If total consumption has reached the configured limit, we can
     * stop
     */
    if (*total_consumed >= WORK_MAX) {
       pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex);
      break;
    }

    /*
     * Remove the next item from the queue. Increment the count of the
     * total consumed. Note that item_consumed is a local copy so this
     * thread can retain a memory of which item it consumed even if
     * others are busy consuming them. 
     */
    queueRemove (fifo, &item_consumed);
    (*total_consumed)++;
    do_work(CONSUMER_CPU,CONSUMER_CPU);

    printf ("con %d:   %d.\n", my_tid, item_consumed);

    pthread_cond_signal(fifo->notFull);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex);

    
    
    
  }

  printf("con %d:   exited\n", my_tid);
  return (NULL);
}

/***************************************************
 *   Main allocates structures, creates threads,   *
 *   waits to tear down.                           *
 ***************************************************/
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t *con;
  int        cons;
  int       *concount;

  queue     *fifo;
  int        i;

  pthread_t *pro;
  int       *procount;
  int        pros;

  pcdata    *thread_args;

  /*
   * Check the number of arguments and determine the numebr of
   * producers and consumers
   */
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Usage: producer_consumer number_of_producers number_of_consumers\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  pros = atoi(argv[1]);
  cons = atoi(argv[2]);

  /*
   * Create the shared queue
   */
  fifo = queueInit ();
  if (fifo ==  NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "main: Queue Init failed.\n");
    exit (1);
  }

  /*
   * Create a counter tracking how many items were produced, shared
   * among all producers, and one to track how many items were
   * consumed, shared among all consumers.
   */
  procount = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
  if (procount == NULL) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "procount allocation failed\n"); 
    exit(1); 
  }
  
  concount = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int));
  if (concount == NULL) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "concount allocation failed\n"); 
    exit(1); 
  }

  /*
   * Create arrays of thread structures, one for each producer and
   * consumer
   */
  pro = (pthread_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_t) * pros);
  if (pro == NULL) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "pros\n"); 
    exit(1); 
  }

  con = (pthread_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_t) * cons);
  if (con == NULL) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "cons\n"); 
    exit(1); 
  }

  /*
   * Create the specified number of producers
   */
  for (i=0; i<pros; i++){ 
    /*
     * Allocate memory for each producer's arguments
     */
    thread_args = (pcdata *)malloc (sizeof (pcdata));
    if (thread_args == NULL) {
      fprintf (stderr, "main: Thread_Args Init failed.\n");
      exit (1);
    }

    /*
     * Fill them in and then create the producer thread
     */
    thread_args->q     = fifo;
    thread_args->count = procount;
    thread_args->tid   = i;
    pthread_create (&pro[i], NULL, producer, thread_args);
  }

  /*
   * Create the specified number of consumers
   */
  for (i=0; i<cons; i++){
    /*
     * Allocate space for next consumer's args
     */
    thread_args = (pcdata *)malloc (sizeof (pcdata));
    if (thread_args == NULL) {
      fprintf (stderr, "main: Thread_Args Init failed.\n");
      exit (1);
    }

    /*
     * Fill them in and create the thread
     */
    thread_args->q     = fifo;
    thread_args->count = concount;
    thread_args->tid   = i;
    pthread_create (&con[i], NULL, consumer, thread_args);
  }

  /*
   * Wait for the create producer and consumer threads to finish
   * before this original thread will exit. We wait for all the
   * producers before waiting for the consumers, but that is an
   * unimportant detail.
   */
  for (i=0; i<pros; i++)
    pthread_join (pro[i], NULL);
  for (i=0; i<cons; i++)
    pthread_join (con[i], NULL);

  /*
   * Delete the shared fifo, now that we know there are no users of
   * it. Since we are about to exit we could skip this step, but we
   * put it here for neatness' sake.
   */
  queueDelete (fifo);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to run the producer-consumer problem while
> using `pthread_cond_signal()` instead of `pthread_cond_broadcast()`,
> however, I attempted a lot of things and can't seem to do it (if I
> choose n producers and one consumer then the consumer finishes but not
> all producers finish, some are stuck on full queue so the problem
> never finishes executing.

Well that sounds eminently plausible.  If you have multiple threads blocked on a CV, then one signal will wake one of them.  The rest will remain blocked.

I am generally inclined to go the other way.  If you use your CV correctly, then it is safe to always broadcast to it instead of signaling it, but doing the opposite exposes more area for possible bugs, especially when more than two threads are involved.

For the shutdown scenario in particular, I would recommend just using a broadcast.  You need to wake potentially multiple threads, and that's exactly what `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is for.  You could have the main thread do that instead of either consumer or producer if you wish. But if you insist on using only `pthread_cond_signal()` then you must be sure to call that function enough times to wake all threads that may be blocked on the CV.  Again, some or all of those calls could be performed by the main thread.

#### Update

Notwithstanding my above recommendation to broadcast, a relatively good way to obtain clean shutdown with signaling only would be for each producer to signal the notFull CV before terminating.  There are a couple of places you could put that, but I would probably do this, myself:

```
    if (*total_produced >= WORK_MAX) {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(fifo->mutex); //if total work reached then exit
      pthread_cond_signal(fifo->notFull); // other producers should wake up and exit, too
      break;
    }
```

Note that the mutex does not need to be currently locked by the thread that sends a broadcast or signal.

Note also that if you go this route then the consumer wants analogous treatment.

Finally, note that for this particular code, the transformation you are trying to perform is a bad idea from a functional perspective, especially for cases where the numbers of producers and consumers differ.  No matter how many of each you start with, it will tend to reduce to having the same number of active producers and consumers, and probably, over a longer time frame, towards having at most one of each at any given time.  These consequences arise from situations where multiple consumers or multiple producers are blocked on the CV at the same time.

Comment: Putting a signal in `main()` didn't work, I even tried doing the following before joining the threads: 
```
for(z=0; z<pros; z++)
pthread_cond_signal(fifo->notFull);
```

Comment: @Sergio, the main thread has no special distinction from the consumer and producer threads that would affect the operation or effect of `pthread_cond_signal()` or `*_broadcast()`.  However, the *timing* matters.  If you want to use the main thread for cleanup then you must not commence with the signaling or perform the broadcast until the condition for cleanup is actually satisfied.

Comment: I am lost at this point, I tried every placement of signal possible in the consumer thread and in main function and non worked, is it possible that it just doesn't work?

Comment: @Sergio, multithreaded programming is much more difficult than single-threaded, and it requires attention to a whole other set of concepts and considerations.  It is extremely unlikely to find viable solutions to threading problems by trial and error -- generally, you really need to understand the problem before you can fix it.  I have updated this answer with a specific suggested remediation, but again, a better solution would be to not perform this transformation in the first place.

Comment: "Note that the mutex does not need to be currently locked by the thread that sends a broadcast or signal, and it can be marginally more efficient if the mutex is not held at that time." You got it backwards. It's more efficient if the mutex *is* held because that can't possibly make a thread ready-to-run (since it needs the mutex to make forward progress) allowing the implementation to optimize the signal operation entirely in user space. Punch "wait morphing" into your favorite search engine to explain it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, as I understand it, wait morphing is an optimization that reduces the negative impact of waking a thread from CV wait when it cannot immediately obtain the mutex, such as, especially, the one where the signaling thread holds the mutex.  That the negative impact of this course of events can be reduced does not make it better to exercise this path than the one where the woken thread *can* immediately obtain the mutex.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you, this has worked. However, I have few questions if you don't mind: 1.The reason I never considered this is that I thought waking up producers should be always done by consumers, since you did this then I am assuming my understanding is wrong? 2.According to my very basic reasoning, I think I should keep the signal in the consumer as well (this lets the producer wakes up more often as other producers can produce whenever consuming happens), would my reasoning be correct? Execution seems to "agree" with what I said.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Your understanding is incorrect. It really is this simple -- if you signal the c.v. while holding the mutex, that signal *cannot* make a thread ready-to-run because any thread blocked on the c.v. needs the mutex. This makes the signal much cheaper. That's the only relevant performance difference between the two cases.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I have removed the contested claim, but I am not convinced.  Your assertion runs contrary to the one I usually see here on SO and elsewhere, and my (limited) research on the topic has turned up up resources that seem pretty consistent in describing wait morphing as reducing a performance penalty suffered in the relevant case, not as yielding a performance gain relative to the other case.  If you can refer me to an authoritative source that says differently then I would be interested in reviewing it.